# How to create svn repository in eclipse...?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN..
first thing how to create SVN repository location using http?
i want to share a project in my network.??
i have tried to create repository using http

**`http://192.168.1.12:8088/home/svn/svnproject`**

this is ip of my computer.
i have created home/svn/svnproject repository using command

**`svnadmin create /home/svn/svnproject`**

is it correct way or im doing it wrong.??
plz suggest me.

Comment: Please read chapters 1,2,5 and 6 in [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). You then will be able to ask more informed and specific questions. Good luck!